# How to create an output that triggers at a certain point in a loop without stopping the loop?

Tags: java, loops, conditional-statements

I'm trying to sort out the correct code to an assignment I got back from an OOJ class, we are using Java.

I'm struggling with two issues. First, I need the program to calculate compounding growth using the rate provided (6%) and print to console each month's production with each iteration over the course of 24 months. Second, I need to display the month when production passes 7000.I was told by my professor production should pass 7000 on month 10, mine is showing it sooner.

Something is off in my calculation and I'm not sure what I'm overlooking. I'd appreciate any input and general advice on how to improve the code.

> The Freemont Automobile Factory has discovered that the longer a worker has been on the job,
> the more parts the worker can produce. Write an application that computes and displays
> a worker’s anticipated output each month for 24 months assuming the worker starts by producing
> 4,000 parts and increases production by 6 percent each month. Also display the month in which
> production exceeds 7,000 parts (when the worker deserves a raise!).

```
public class IncreasedProduction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //declare variables
        
        double rate = .06;
        double production = 4;
        
        //column titles
        System.out.println("(Parts produced measured in thousands)\n\n"+ "Month" + "   " + "Parts Produced\n");
        
            //counts the number of each iterations
            for(int month = 1; month > 0; month++)
            {   
                production = production*Math.pow(1.0 + rate, month);                                
                
                //displays the monthly total parts produced
                if( month < 25 )
                {
                    //Displays monthly total
                    System.out.println("  " + month + "      " + String.format("%.2f",production) + "\n");
                    
                    //calculates the moment when 7000 parts are first produced and displays a message
                    if( production >= 7 && (production/1.06) < 7) {
                        System.out.println(">>>  You produced 7000 parts in " + month + " months, you deserve a raise. <<<\n");
                }}
                else
                {   //displays number of month and total parts produced at the end of 24 months
                    
                    System.out.println("\nIn " + month + " months you produced " + String.format("%.2f",production) + " parts!");
                    //break
                    month = -1;
                
                }
            }       
    }
}
```

Comment: You say "The code runs as intended but my professor is saying production should pass 7000 after or on 10 months" - only one of those statements can be true :)
Please clarify your question, what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. Essentially the program should print the compounding production total to console after each iteration (measured in months) and stop at 24 months. The program should also print to console a message once we have passed 7000 parts produced. Apparently this should happen at 10 months (iterations) but my code appears to be off because its printing to console sooner.

Comment: @cdutley please edit your question with the precise problem. What is the expected result? What is your program doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculation of the increase of the production does not seem to be correct:

```java
production = production*Math.pow(1.0 + rate, month);
```

as it is multiplying the increase twice:

1. K = (1 + r)^month
2. production = production * K

So the monthly production increase grows significantly after the first month, which is evident after adding the delta and increase calculation to the output:

```
delta=240 -> 6.00%    1      4240.00
delta=524 -> 12.36%    2      4764.06
delta=910 -> 19.10%    3      5674.08
delta=1489 -> 26.25%    4      7163.39
>>>  You produced 7000 parts in 4 months, you deserve a raise. <<<
```

This is resolved by correction to count the increase only one time:

```
 production = Math.round(production*(1.0 + rate));
// or equivalent
// production = Math.round(4000*Math.pow(1.0 + rate, month));
```

output

```
Month   Parts Produced

  1      4240.00
  2      4494.00
  3      4764.00
  4      5050.00
  5      5353.00
  6      5674.00
  7      6014.00
  8      6375.00
  9      6758.00
  10      7163.00

>>>  You produced 7000 parts in 10 months, you deserve a raise. <<<

  11      7593.00
```